# Javascript functions not being called on ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios

This has probably been gone over before but I can't find anything definitive. I'm developing a site using javascript but when testing the site on ios none of the javascript is working. Javascript is enabled on my phone.

```
function loadEverything() {
   content.innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
window.onload = loadEverything();
```

This works in a desktop browser but not the mobile browser on my iphone.

Comment: Yes, this has probably been answered before. You aren't attaching a function to `window.onload` here, you are attaching the result of a function call to `window.onload`. The function still runs, but rather than waiting for the page to load, it runs immediately.

Comment: Luca is right. The last line should be `window.onload = loadEverything;
`

Comment: Nothing seems to be working... I've tried adding an event listener, using undefined's suggestion, javascript still doesn't appear to be working in any of my ios browsers, Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Ok so apparently javascript works if it's in my index.html file. So if I put `<script> alert('Hello World'); </script>` in my index.html file it works on mobile. But when I try to use javascript in a separate file it stops working. Do I have to link to js files differently for mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was declaring variables with `let` instead of `var`. Figured out I could use Safari's 'User Agent' feature on desktop to simulate the ios safari browser while on desktop and then use the developer features to find out what was going on.

Wasn't expecting that one

Answer (score 0):

Use an event listener, for instance, on DOMContentLoaded browser event instead, unless of course you really need the window load stuff.